# Bundle pooling and p2 director

Tags: eclipse

I am experimenting with using bundle pools with p2 director and not having a lot of luck. Here is the command that I am running:

```
java
-Xmx512m
-cp
[launcher-path]
org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main
-application
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director
-metadataRepository
[repo]
-artifactRepository
[repo]
-destination
[destination]
-bundlepool
[pool]
-installIU
[iu]
```

This does indeed place installed bundles in the separate pool location. However, when I run this command again, the plugins and features already in the pool are *not* re-used. Based on the time it takes for the command to run and the fact that files in the pool have new time stamps, it looks like p2 director re-downloads and re-writes exact same bundles and features into the pool.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Below link contains very good explanation for the same thing.

https://ekkescorner.wordpress.com/2008/06/29/eclipse-ganymede-p2-shared-installations-bundle-pool/

https://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox/p2/Getting_Started

I am not sure but may be below is usefull.

You can also use an own extra dropins folder: simply add a parameter into eclipse.ini (/your_path/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS):

-Dorg.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins.directory= /your_path/e34shared_dropin